# Click event on mapImage in amCharts 4

Tags: javascript, dictionary, amcharts

I have added a custom marker to my map using the following guide: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/custom-html-elements-map-markers/ but I can't for the life of me work out how to add a click event to this marker!

i have tried the following with no results:

`imageSeries.mapImages.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
console.log("clicked on ", ev.target);
}, this);`

I can add a click event using jQuery however I need the map to zoom and center to the marker when clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using [custom HTML map markers](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/custom-html-elements-map-markers/), you'll want to tie click events to those whether via vanilla js or jQuery.

In their click event handlers, if you have a reference to their associated `MapImage`, you can try `chart.zoomToMapObject(mapImageReferenceHere);` (see our guide "[Zooming to map area on click](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/zooming-to-map-area-on-click/)"). You may have to adjust the positioning of the HTML markers so they're better-centered according along the `mapImage`.

Forking our demo, all you'd have to add is the following to the `createCustomMarker` function:

```js
  holder.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    chart.zoomToMapObject(image);
  });
```

See the fork here:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/15dbf72f74b61fb83cd0754a96fa2c49

PS

Instead of `imageSeries.mapImages.events.on` you'd want to place events on the `template`, i.e. `imageSeries.mapImages.template.events.on("hit", function(ev) { ... } );`. Please check out our guide on our concept of [List Templates](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/list-templates/) in amCharts v4.

Answer (score 0):

What i think is the event is triggered on a template.
So I used the following approach -

To create pointers -
// Create image series
var imageSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapImageSeries());

```
    // Create a circle image in image series template so it gets replicated to all new images
    var imageSeriesTemplate = imageSeries.mapImages.template;
    var circle = imageSeriesTemplate.createChild(am4core.Circle);
```

In my case i required pointers as circles.

Then fill in desired data in the Image series.

Trigger event -
imageSeriesTemplate.events.on("hit", function(e) {console.log("clicked on:",e);});